# Finding the content for a page

Tags: wordpress

I'm trying to make a change to an existing wordpress site. The main page is generated by the following:

```
<?php

get_header();
the_post();
if( get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_ebor_disable_header', true ) !== 'on' )
    get_template_part('loop/content','pagetitle');
the_content();
get_footer('onepage');
```

I've verified this by ripping out `the_content()` and seeing the page go mostly blank. However, I can't find where the content is stored.

Searching in the database is returning nothing (`udz_posts` table), and it doesn't seem to be in the source files. Is there a way to determine where its fetching the content from?

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to help you out. Is this the code for the homepage? If yes, and you would like to edit the content of it. It really depends on how it is set up. But you can actually right an HTML code in there to make it appear. However, to maximize the use of wordpress, you can set a page to be the homepage and add content there.

Comment: Rodney, that's the homepage, but there's no hard-coded content and I can't seem to find it in the database or via searches. Its got to live -somewhere- but I don't know where.

Comment: Ok, try logging in the wordpress site. Then go to Pages and look for the page that says "- Front Page". If you find one, that should be it. Try by editing. Let me know if you can't find one